# Using the '\\' command in LaTeX lists' items

Tags: lists

I need to update some LaTeX files containing lists. I've noticed that all but the last ones items in the lists end with the `\\` command, e.g.:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item1 text\\
  \item Item2 text\\
  \item Item3 text
\end{itemize}
```

What do these `\\` commands do? Is it safe to remove them?

Comment: \\ is a very basic LaTeX command and it is probably described at the beginning of any LaTeX tutorial. It just adds a line break. In an itemized environment, it starts a new indented paragraph, but without a bullet. What it does with your example is to add an empty paragraph and this way it increases the iter-item space. It is up to you to decide if it is or not safe to remove them, but definitely it will not break your code.

Comment: It is not only safe, but also advised to remove them. Outside of tables, there is nearly no place at all where using `//` is correct. In the specific case you show they are the cause of the underfull box warnings

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to remove them; they are not needed. If you use a LaTeX IDE like TeXstudio, etc. to generate an example itemized list or numerated list they do not include the line break sequence `\\` at the end of each item.